# Add Items to QListWidget add design time

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to add items to a ListWidget during design time. I am using QT Designer however I cannot find any options to add items to a list widget at design time. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to simply insert a `QListWidget` in a form when design your GUI in Qt designer. Double clicking on the `QListWidget` will open another `Edit List Widget` dialog that will allow you to customize it: insert new items, change properties etc.